# Woo commerce how to display child category titles along with the parent one?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am a new developer in my 1st role and I'm working on someone else's WordPress site.

I'm working on a e-commerce site for a client and i need to display child category titles below the parent title on the on the product page.

I cant find a echo for calling sub-category.

Comment: Kevin can you not ask someone at the place you are working to help you? Seems like something they should explain not the internet.

Comment: No because the developer that was previously working on the site has left and I am the only developer at the place I'm working at. But thanks for the advice.